# Convert PHP's dot concatenation of a binary part + string part to C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm working on rewriting a piece of PHP code to C#. This code is used for password hashing. In the first step it produces a string like "password{salt}", than hashes it via sha512 hash algorithm. After that a loop is hashing the combination of the first hash and the salt again for 5000 iterations.

The PHP Code looks like this:

```
<?php
$password = 'abc';
$salt = 'def';
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i=1; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
}

$encodedPassword = base64_encode($digest);

//$encodedPassword contains the final hash code
```

I was able to get it working without the loop (with just the first hash() call). So the main hashing and base64 encoding is done correctly. I found out that this part is what I cannot manage to rewrite in C#:

```
$digest.$salted
```

$digest seems to be a binary representation since PHP's hash() function was used with "true" as the last parameter (see [PHP hash - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)). $salted is a string. Both get somehow magically combined by PHP's dot / concat operator. I guess there will be some sort of standard conversion from binary to string under the hood when using the dot operator with a non-string operand.

This is my code so far:

```
void Main()
{
    string password = "abc";
    string salt = "def";
    string salted = String.Format("{0}{{{1}}}", password, salt);
    byte[] digest = hash(salted);

    for(int i = 1; i < 1; i++) 
    {
        digest = hash(String.Format("{0}{1}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(digest), salted));
    }
    var encodedPassword = System.Convert.ToBase64String(digest);
    //$encodedPassword should contain the final hash code
}

static byte[] hash(string toHash) 
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
    return sha512.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHash));
}
```

As you see I tried to convert the hash bytes back to a string with System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString() and then append the salt but that doesn't produce the same output as the PHP code.

I would be very happy if someone could help me on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try different encodings like ascii? are u sure the binary hash is in utf8?

Comment: It was indeed a problem with encodings (like José's answer also pointed out). Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP version you loop 4999 times, while in the C# version 0. The second problem is that the returned bytes from hash() have no encoding at all.

This should give you the same result as the PHP version:

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
    var saltedUtf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salted);

    for(int i = 1; i < 5000; i++) 
    {
        digest = sha512.ComputeHash(digest.Concat(saltedUtf8Bytes).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much José! The encoding and your solution with using .Concat() to do the combination solved my problem.